# What's Install scala 2.12.2 and Lightbend Activator mean?

Tags: git, scala, github

I'm learning about NLP, and I have to clone project from this github
https://github.com/panggi/pujangga
I try to following local setup instruction

1. Install scala 2.12.2 and Lightbend Activator
2. Clone the project
3. $ git clone git@github.com:panggi/pujangga.git
4. Download the dependencies
5. $ cd pujangga
6. $ activator
7. Pretrained word2vec model can be downloaded here https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B5YTktu2dOKKNUY1OWJORlZTcUU&export=download
8. Run Application
9. $ export WORD2VEC_FILE=/path/to/word2vec_wiki_id
10. $ activator run
11. Access on http://localhost:9000

I've tried to

1. download jdk8 and install it
2. download scala-2.12.2.msi and install it

but I have no understanding about "Lightbend Activator", what lightbend activator means?

Comment: Activator was EOL'ed years ago; those must be old instructions. Try installing sbt instead and simply replacing `activator` with `sbt` everywhere above. It might work, it's worth a try. Note that you don't need to install Scala, sbt will download Scala JARs for you.

Comment: @SethTisue thanks, currently I try to install Intellij and load project in intellij